# How to check if all characters in a string are the same?

Tags: php

How to check if all characters in a string are identical, or in other words whether there are at least two different characters in a string?

---

This is my non-working attempt:

```
<?php
$isSame = False;
$word = '1111';//in any language
$word_arr = array();
for ($i=0;$i<strlen($word);$i++) {
    $word_arr[] = $word[$i];
    if($word_arr[$i] == $word[$i]) $isSame = True;
}
var_dump($isSame);
?>
```

Comment: Please make sure your code is in readable form

Comment: "Identical of a word characters" does not make much sense as a question. Please try to explain more what you're trying to do.

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/explode http://php.net/array_count_values

Comment: Could you explain better what are you trying to do?

Comment: What does not work?
Are you getting True or false?
That code should work. I just tested it.

Comment: i want to check word characters , for example if all characters of a word is same , show user a warning

Comment: @MarcB RTLM: http://php.net/count_chars

Comment: @salathe: whaddaya know. learn something new every day, even after all this time.

Comment: Here's another one - simple, cheap, multi-byte safe: `$isSame = ( '' == str_replace(mb_substr($word, -1), '', $word) );`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are trying to see if a word is just a repetition of a character (ie. it only has one different character).

You can use a simple regex for that:

```
$word = '11111';
if (preg_match('/^(.)\1*$/u', $word)) {
    echo "Warning: $word has only one different character";
}
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
^   => start of line (to be sure that the regex does not match
       just an internal substring)
(.) => get the first character of the string in backreference \1
\1* => next characters should be a repetition of the first
       character (the captured \1)
$   => end of line (see start of line annotation)
```

So, in short, make sure that the string only has repetitions of its first character and no other character.

Comment: This regex doesn't support some languages like Russian or Arabic!

Comment: @amature if the string is UTF8 encoded, use the [`u`](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) (`PCRE_UTF8`) pattern modifier ([docs](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers)).

Comment: @salathe can you paste new code here?

Comment: @amature change `/^(.)\1*$/` to `/^(.)\1*$/u`  (spot the difference)

Comment: Here's another one - simple, cheap, multi-byte safe: `$isSame = ( '' == str_replace(mb_substr($word, -1), '', $word) );`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`count_chars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php) for your string with second parameter of 1 or 3.
If your string consists of one repeating character, e.g.:

```
$word = '1111';

// first check with parameter = 1
$res = count_chars($word, 1);
var_dump($res);
// $res will be one element array, you can check it by count/sizeof

// second check with parameter = 3
$res = count_chars($word, 3);
var_dump($res);
// $res will be string which consists of 1 character, you can check it by strlen
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears like you want to check if all characters are same

```
<?php
$isSame = True;
$word = '1111';
$first=$word[0];
for ($i=1;$i<strlen($word);$i++) {
    if($word[$i]!=$first) $isSame = False;
}
var_dump($isSame);
?>
```

[PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bms-1e8)